# Node.js reference path absolute

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webstorm

I have a Node.js project developed in WebStorm IDE

My project structure is:

A root folder named "root" that contains 2 folders: "main" and "typings". "main" contains one file named "foo.ts", "typings" contains one file named "bar.d.ts".

In foo.ts I added a reference path to bar.d.ts.

This works:

```
///<reference path="../typings/bar.d.ts" />
```

This does not work (getting "File not found"):

```
///<reference path="/typings/bar.d.ts" />
```

This does not work either:

```
///<reference path="/root/typings/bar.d.ts" />
```

How can I get rid of the 2 dots (..)?

Comment: So this is a tag you're outputting in the HTML generated by Node, right? If so, `/` would be webroot, i.e. the root of your website, not the server, so where are you serving up your "index" from ?

Comment: @adeneo no! I do not have client side in my project at all. It's all server side. No HTML! I use this tag in order for TypeScript to not complain that bar.d.ts doesn't exist.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the 2 dots?

Comment: @drinchev because if I moved foo.ts to another directory level I would need to change all its paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get rid of the 2 dots (..)

You can if you provide *absolute path on disk*. This is however not what you want.

If you want *relative to project root*, that isn't supported for reference tags.

## Fix

Just use `tsconfig.json` and make sure it includes both foo and bar using [e.g. files](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/files.html)